# Creating Adapter Pattern where methods need different objects in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, adapter

I am struggling with a design decision and hopefully one of you can help me. Thank you in advance for your time.

I am trying to create a library which can use existing API's of similar products.

## ProducerA

Attributes: `UserTypeA`

Operation: `CreateMeeting(MeetingTypeA,UserTypeA)`

## ProducerB

Attributes: `UserTypeB`

Operation: `CreateMeeting(MeetingTypeB,UserTypeB)`

## AdapterInterface:

`IMyAdapter`

Attributes: `IMyUserType`

Methods: `CreateMeeting(IMyMeeting, IMyUserType)`

### Adapter for producer A:

`ProducerAdapterA: IMyAdapter`

Methods: `CreateMeeting( xxxx, xxxx)`
etc

I have an interface `IMyAdapter` and it's implementations as `Producer(a/b)Adapter`...  My problem is the parameters of each method.

For example `ProducerA`'s `CreateMeeting` method takes a meeting type which is different than `ProducerB`'s `GenerateMeeting` method's `MeetingType`.

I created the following in my Adapter related library to be able to create a generic class for meeting :

`IMeeting`,

`IMeetingAdapterTypeA: IMeeting, IMeetingTypeA  // IMeetingTypeA comes from producer's library`

`MeetingAdapterTypeA : IMeetingAdapterTypeA`

and for producerB

`IMeetingAdapterTypeB: IMeeting, IMeetingTypeB`

`MeetingAdapterTypeB: IMeetingAdapterTypeB`

However this requires too many cast operations back and forward meanwhile, any user of my adapter should be aware of these casts.

So my question is, is there a better way to handle method parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control over MeetingTypeA and MeetingTypeB?

Comment: I don't have however I expect similar properties with different names.

Comment: Make a `MeetingTemplate` object that your API uses exclusively, that contains the superset of all data you can have about meetings.  Then at the last moment, before calling createMeeting on the appropriate producer, instantiate the class they need using your template.

Comment: Don't create adapters for `MeetingTypeA` and `MeetingTypeB`. The `ProducerAdapter` should be responsible for translating `IMeeting` to concrete `MeetingTypeA` or `MeetingTypeB`.

Comment: Hi TumT, I don't create adapters for MeetingTypeA and B. They are just interfaces to be used in the related adapter. On the other hand names I preferred might cause this confusion.